# How many boys may dance with boys and girls with girls? Forming Dance Pairs - Combinatorics -

Tags: combinatorics

At a party there are 20 girls and 20 boys.
How many dance pairs can be formed if boys may dance with boys, and girls with girls?

I have taken a smaller set of 3 girls and 3 boys to try and understand this problem. Altogether this is 6 people. We can form pairs (where the order of the partners do not matter) in such a way:

- From 6 people, choose 2 of them to form a pair -> C(6,2) = 15, then
- from 4 people, choose 2 of them to form the next pair -> C(4,2) = 6, then
- from the last 2 people, choose 2 to form the final pair -> C(2,2) = 1

Therefore forming (15)(6)(1) = 90 dance pairs

Am I understanding this question correctly? Is my reasoning sound, if so can this be extended to the problem of 20 boys and 20 girls?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This would be correct *if* there were such a thing as the "*first*" pair and this is somehow distinguishable from the "*second*" pair and so on...  This is not the common interpretation of the problem where we forget which pair was which.  How much do you think you overcounted by as a result?

Comment: An alternate method of counting... Among your people, one of them is going to be the youngest.  Choose who their dancing partner is.  Then, from those unused remaining participants one of these will now be the new youngest.  Choose who their dancing partner is.  Continue in this fashion until all have their dancing partners assigned.

Comment: Can boys dance with girls?

Comment: @Henry I should hope so, otherwise with 3 girls and 3 boys, we'd have two unused people at the end who weren't able to find a dancing partner.  Given the OP's attempt, that is clearly not their interpretation.

Comment: @JMoravitz I understand your second comment on the alternate method of counting but could you explain how my proposed method for solving this is overcounting? Thank You

Comment: Again, you incorrectly applied some significance to the order in which you selected the pairs.  There is no "first" pair and "second" pair etc...  You overcounted by a factor of $n!$.  in the case of $3$ boys and $3$ girls, a factor of $3!$.  Indeed, $90/3!=15 = 5\times 3\times 1 = 5!!$ and in general, $\frac{(2n!)}{2^nn!} = (2n-1)!!$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@JMoravitz gave you beautiful comment to teach it to you . I am writing this answer to give you another view.

It is said that boys can dace with boys , girls can dance with girls , boys and girls can dance ,as well . So, it is understod that every one can dance with anyone .Hence ,we have $40$ people to dance.

Now , i want you to think that these $40$ people are like $40$ distinct balls . Moreover , think that dancing is the same as getting in a box with another ball , and all boxes are same , because it is not mentioned that dancing is different type. Lets assume that all of them dacing tango.

Now , the question turned out to be placing $40$ distinct balls into $20$ identical boxes where each box will have exactly $2$ balls.

To solve it , firstly think that boxes are different , so there are $\binom{40}{2}$ ways for the first box , there are $\binom{38}{2}$ ways for the second box , .... , there are $\binom{2}{2}$ ways for the $20th$ box . Multiplicaiton of these binomal coefficients is equal to $\frac {40!}{2^{20}}$

However , the boxes were identical , to make them identical again divide the result by $20!$.

So , the answer is $$\frac {40!}{2^{20} \times 20!}$$